# Call a specific controller's action from form inputs

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

In my view where you can see other users' profile, I want to add a small form only visible for admins and moderators where they can select the role they want to give to the displayed user.

I created a Controller with an action for each promotion type (Becasue the requires are different for each (for exemple : only admins can promote someone admin role) and can be changed).

Now I am not sure if I should :

*Create a  in my Twig view and somehow (please help me), redirect to the action accordingly to the inputs (like this maybe)

```
{% if is_granted("ROLE_MODERATEUR") %}
                        Rendre ce membre : 
                                <form name="form" >
                                <select>
                                    <option >Sélectionner un rôle</option>
                                    {% if is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN") %}
                                    <option value="{{ path('annuaire_admin_admin', {id:membre.id}) }}" >Administrateur</option>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <option value="{{ path('annuaire_admin_moderateur', {id:membre.id})}}" >Modérateur</option>
                                    <option value="{{ path('annuaire_admin_actif', {id:membre.id})}}" >Utilisateur actif</option>
                                    <option value="{{ path('annuaire_admin_passif', {id:membre.id}) }}" >Utilisateur passif</option>
                                </select>
                                <input type="submit" value="Confirmer">
                                </form>
                    {% endif %}
```

*Create something more "symfony like" like a FormType or a class to handle this functionnality.

Here is my Controller:

```
namespace Cua\AnnuaireBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function adminAction($id)
    {   
        if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }elseif (isset($id)){

            $membre =$this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('CuaUserBundle:Membre')
            ->find($id);

        // Ou nul si aucun membre  n'a été trouvé avec l'id $id
            if($membre === null)
            {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Membre[id='.$id.'] inexistant.');

            }
            $membre->setRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
        }
    }

    public function moderateurAction($id)
    {
        if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_MODERATEUR')) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }elseif (isset($id)){

            $membre =$this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('CuaUserBundle:Membre')
            ->find($id);

            // Ou nul si aucun membre  n'a été trouvé avec l'id $id
            if($membre === null)
            {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Membre[id='.$id.'] inexistant.');

            }
            if (!$membre->hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN") or $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')){
                $membre->setRole("ROLE_MODERATEUR");
            }
        }
    }

    public function actifAction($id)
    {
        if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_MODERATEUR')) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }elseif (isset($id)){

            $membre =$this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('CuaUserBundle:Membre')
            ->find($id);

            // Ou nul si aucun membre  n'a été trouvé avec l'id $id
            if($membre === null)
            {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Membre[id='.$id.'] inexistant.');

            }
            if (!$membre->hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN") or $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')){
                $membre->setRole("ROLE_UTILISATEUR_ACTIF");
            }
        }
    }

    public function passifAction($id)
    {
        if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_MODERATEUR')) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }elseif (isset($id)){

            $membre =$this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('CuaUserBundle:Membre')
            ->find($id);

            // Ou nul si aucun membre  n'a été trouvé avec l'id $id
            if($membre === null)
            {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Membre[id='.$id.'] inexistant.');

            }
            if (!$membre->hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN") or $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')){
                $membre->setRole("ROLE_UTILISATEUR_PASSIF");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got what seems like two separate questions there.

[Symfony Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)

*Basic Form Structure*

For creating the form, I agree with Haig that making a FormType is probably best: it packages up everything very nicely, and is easy.  Your form is quite simple, though (one field), so it's up to you.  Either way, I would use Symfony's Form infrastructure (generating HTML, handling submissions and processing HTTP data into objects), it's very convenient.

*Multiple Actions*

As for how your form submission can cause different activities based on the dropdown, in your example you've got several Roles as the options in your dropdown, and you want each option to hit a different Symfony Action.  This is possible - you'd could use Javascript to alter the form action according to the option chosen - but untidy.  Nicer, and more fitting with Symfony Forms, would be to have them all going to one Action (`roleAction`, for example), and then within that Action examining the `role` field and executing another method to carry out the required task (these methods would be similar to your existing Actions).

e.g.

**FormType**

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RoleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('role', 'choice', ['choices' => ['admin'=>'Administrateur', 'actif'=>'Actif']]) //etc etc
            ->add('save', 'submit');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'role';
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function roleAction(Request $request, $id)
{   
    //We could create an object representing the data behind the form here,
    //but we don't have to.  If we don't, we get a simple array back
    //http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class
    $form = $this->createForm(new RoleType() ); //Object representing form itself

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid() )
    {
         //Get the data from the form, in the form of an array
         $data = $form->getData();

         //Get role chosen from form data (key is fieldname) and choose appropriate method to make change
         switch($data['role'] ) 
             case "moderateur":
                 $this->donneModerateur($id);
                 break;
             case "actif":
                 $this->donneActif($id);
                 break;
             //etc etc
    }
}

private function donneModerateur($id)
{
    //Similar to previous Action
}
```

You'll need to set the Form to submit to a URL containing the user ID, something like `->setAction($this->generateUrl('annuaire_admin_', ['id'=>$user->getId()]))`

Comment: OK, I understand much better my issue and your answer is pretty clear :) I am going to implement this solution and get back to you but I am convinced that it'll will work ;)

Comment: I never used "setAction" before, I suppose that in this case, I should write nothing in my "<form>" in my twig view right?

Comment: Sorry, that assumes that you have made a FormType, passed a Form to your View, and then gone `{{ form(form) }}` (simplest possible example) in your View to render the Form.  If you do that, then you don't write any HTML for the form at all, and everything including the `action` comes from the Form object.  Even if you choose to render your form in a more complex way in the template, you probably let Symfony create your `<form>` tag, including the action.

Comment: I also assumed that the page this is on already has a main form, which is why you need to set a different action for this additional admin-only form.  If it's the only form on the page then you could use the main controller to handle form submission, keeping the default action - the controller would either show the user profile page, or carry out the role change, depending on if the form had been submitted.

Comment: I've added a RoleType example Form, and removed the need for a class just to hold the data behind the form.

Comment: 1) Indeed, it is the only form on the page, so i'll get the methode on my controller then call the adminController to handle changes

2)I don't understand how I could "let Symfony create your <form> tag, including the action." because as soon as I extract the "widget", etc, I use them inside <form> tags

EDIT : thanks for the modifications, it was exactly that "getData()" I didn't know and I was looking for =)

Comment: If you go `{{ form(form) }}` in Twig you'll get everything you need for the form, including `<form>`, `<input>`, everything.  That's will literally give you a fully working form.  If you want more control, then for example you go `{{ form_start(form) }}`, then some HTML and `{{ form_widget(role) }}`, then `{{ form_end(form) }}`, or whatever you want.

Comment: ok, I'll use the {{ form_start(form) }} and {{ form_end(form) }} from now on =)
I knew the {{ form(form) }} but never used it since it's impossible to customise the view :/

Answer (score 0):

I tend to favor using Symfony form type classes over embedding forms directly into a view. This is because form type classes are extremely reusable, the form handling and validation is taken care of for you (resulting in much leaner controllers and models), and it's very easy to extend if you ever need to add more fields.

I'd certainly recommend going that route. In my experience, once you understand how to create and use Symfony form models and types, it really feels quite clumsy and inefficient going back to hardcoded forms. How to do this is well documented:

[Creating Forms from Classes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-form-creating-form-classes)

Comment: So, you mean that I need to build a form directly linked to my user entity (CuaUserBundle:Membre) and then insert something {{ render(controller("CuaAnnuaireBundle:Admin:form")) }} which will build a form, using my formType and rendering it with a specific view such as : 

<form action="{{ path('cua_annuaire_admin_form') }}" {{ method="POST">
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>
</form>



? Is that correct?

Comment: Linking directly to a User entity can be convenient, because it'll set the current value for you.  You can define your form to only map the one field ('role') that you care about.  You'll still have to handle how to react to the user's choice.  It's not necessary though.  As for the form, it would be something like what you've said there, but typically you would only do formatting HTML yourself, you'd let Symfony render the `<form>` and submit tags too, setting the action in advance if it's not the same as the current page (which is the default).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if it's here that i should post, but the commentary section is too short.
So here is my MainController(ProfilController):

```
<?php

namespace Cua\AnnuaireBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Cua\AnnuaireBundle\Form\Type\RoleType;
class ProfilController extends Controller
{

    public function voirAction($id)
    {   
        $request=$this->get('request');
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $admin=$this->get('admin');
            $admin->roleAction($request, $id);
        }
        if (isset($id))
        {   

            $membre =$this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('CuaUserBundle:Membre')
            ->find($id);

        // Ou nul si aucun membre  n'a été trouvé avec l'id $id
            if($membre === null)
            {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Membre[id='.$id.'] inexistant.');

            }
        }else{
            $membre=$this->getUser();
        }
        $form=$this->CreateForm(new RoleType());
        $postes=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CuaAnnuaireBundle:Poste')->listerPostes($membre);
        $cheerups=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CuaAnnuaireBundle:Cheerup')->listerCheerups($membre);
        return $this->render('CuaAnnuaireBundle:Profil:voir.html.twig', array('membre' => $membre, 'postes'=>$postes, 'form'=>$form->CreateView(), 'cheerups' =>$cheerups
        ));
    }
}
```

And here is my modified AdminController:

```
<?php

namespace Cua\AnnuaireBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Cua\AnnuaireBundle\Form\Type\RoleType;
class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function roleAction($donnees, $id)
    {
        //We could create an object representing the data behind the form here,
        //but we don't have to.  If we don't, we get a simple array back
        $form2 = $this->createForm(new RoleType() ); //Object representing form itself

        $form2->handleRequest($donnees);

            if ($form2->isValid() )
            {
                 //Get the data from the form, in the form of an array
                 $data = $form2->getData();

                 //Get role chosen from form data (key is fieldname) and choose appropriate method to make change
                 switch($data['role'] ) { 
                     case "admin":
                         $this->donneAdmin($id);
                         break;//etc
```

I use the RoleType Frumious suggested.
When I submit the form, I get this exeption : "FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\CuaProject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php line 163"

I am not sure about my use of namespace :

**I call to the AdminController passing of the "$donnees" wich may alter the type of "$request". Maybe it is unnecesseray because I could still access the "$request" in my Admin:roleAction knowing the namespace is the same?

*I named the form in AdminController"form2" because the namespace being the same, I wanted to avoid conflict (was it necessary?)

Comment: I'd normally stick additional info onto the end of the Question, or make a completely new Question (and link back to this Question).  I'll have a look though.

Comment: I think you need to have a type for your `$donnees` variable: `(Request $donnees, $id)`.  Otherwise the Controller doesn't get a Request.  The error may be a null reference inside `$form2->handleRequest($donnees)`

Comment: $form2 is just a variable, it can be called anything you like.  When you pass it to the View you give it the name that you'll actually use in Twig to reference the form, which is just `form` in the examples but since you may have multiple forms you're free to be more descriptive.

Comment: The error was with the CreateForm(), because AdminController is called as a service , so he couldn't implement this method. So i create the form in my MainController and pass the form to the AdminController. But I get another similar problem : I cant acces the security context as I did with a controller. So I followed http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/security/securing_services.html. but still got the fatal-error when i called security context. So I finally used JMS Bundle